# AWS Cognito - Create user without sending them a verification email

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to disable the verification process for some users that I register myself(admin).

I've added the pre-signup lambda like the documentation says:

````
```exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

// Confirm the user
    event.response.autoConfirmUser = true;

// Set the email as verified if it is in the request
if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty("email")) {
    event.response.autoVerifyEmail = true;
}

// Set the phone number as verified if it is in the request
if (event.request.userAttributes.hasOwnProperty("phone_number")) {
    event.response.autoVerifyPhone = true;
}

// Return to Amazon Cognito
callback(null, event);
````

};

And the email verification is still coming to the user.

I've also tried using the **adminConfirmSignUp** api to confirm the user right after I create it with **adminCreateUser**. But this is the error i'm getting when using the **adminConfirmSignUp**

> { NotAuthorizedException: User cannot be confirmed. Current status is FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD

Is there any other way that I can make it to not send the verification email to some users?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got this to working by just including these 2 properties inside the request when creating the user.

```
DesiredDeliveryMediums: [],
MessageAction: "SUPPRESS"
```

No need for pre-signup lambda.